NextJS 14 middleware not redirecting correctly
I'm facing an issue with nextjs middleware redirection.
I have the following auth process :

User only have access to "/auth/login"
User logs in, and only have access to "/"

However, the middleware doesn't redirect correctly to "/" when user is already logged in.
This is the middleware :
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import unauthorizedRoutes from "./utils/routes";
import evaluateTokensStatus from "./utils/evaluateTokens";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  let tokensStatus = evaluateTokensStatus();

  const isAuthenticated =
    tokensStatus === "valid" || tokensStatus === "expired";

  const isUnauthorizedRoute = unauthorizedRoutes.some((route) =>
    request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(route)
  );

  console.log("isUnauthorizedRoute", isUnauthorizedRoute);
  console.log("isAuthenticated", isAuthenticated);

  if (!isAuthenticated && !isUnauthorizedRoute) {
    NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/auth/login", request.url));
  } else if (isAuthenticated && isUnauthorizedRoute) {
    console.log("should redirect to /");
    NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", request.url));
  } else {
    console.log("should continue");
    NextResponse.next();
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)"],
};

I manage to get the console.log("should redirect to /") correctly, however nothing happens.
I get a redirect in my network tab.
I tried using another version with return statement, but it is the same, however it doesn't work for redirecting when user is not authenticated, that's why I deleted those returns statement.

My recommendations used next-auth to make your management session more easy.
You can install next-auth in this link
https://next-auth.js.org/
My sample middleware when using next-auth
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

function removeContentLengthIfTransferEncoding(req: NextRequest) {
  if (req.headers.get("transfer-encoding")) {
    req.headers.delete("content-length");
  }
}

export default withAuth(
  function middleware(req) {
    removeContentLengthIfTransferEncoding(req);

    const value = req.nextauth.token;
    if (!value && req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/admin/")) {
      return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL("/login", req.url));
    }
  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      async authorized({ token }) {
        if (!token) {
          return false;
        }

        // // `/me` only requires the user to be logged in
        return !!token;
      },
    },
    pages: {
      signIn: "/login",
    },
  },
);

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/admin/:path*"],
};

And the next.config.ts add this code
 async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/",
        destination: "/login",
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },


Ok, I found out the real problem behind the scene.
The correct way to handle it is using this middleware :
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import unauthorizedRoutes from "./utils/routes";
import evaluateTokensStatus from "./utils/evaluateTokens";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  let tokensStatus = evaluateTokensStatus();

  const isAuthenticated =
    tokensStatus === "valid" || tokensStatus === "expired";

  const isUnauthorizedRoute = unauthorizedRoutes.some((route) =>
    request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(route)
  );

  if (!isAuthenticated && !isUnauthorizedRoute)
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/auth/login", request.url));
  else if (isAuthenticated && isUnauthorizedRoute)
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", request.url));
  else return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    {
      source: "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)",
      missing: [
        // Exclude Server Actions
        { type: "header", key: "next-action" },
      ],
    },
  ],
};


In case if (isAuthenticated && isUnauthorizedRoute) is true, it works easy.
But when case   if (!isAuthenticated && !isUnauthorizedRoute) is true, I had no redirect happening.
The reason was that in this case, my request had a custom middleware used that was redirecting :
"use server";

import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import evaluateAuthStatus from "./evaluateTokens";
import refreshTokens from "./refreshTokens";

export async function backendRequestMiddleware<T>(
  action: () => Promise<T>,
  bypassAuthCheck = false
): Promise<T> {
  if (bypassAuthCheck) return action();

  let tokensStatus = evaluateAuthStatus();

  if (tokensStatus === "expired") {
    await refreshTokens();
    tokensStatus = evaluateAuthStatus();
  }

  if (tokensStatus !== "valid") redirect("/auth/login");

  return action();
}

So in order to make it work correctly I had to add this at the end of my middleware.ts :
 missing: [
        // Exclude Server Actions
        { type: "header", key: "next-action" },
      ],

In the matcher
Now it works perfectly. For more informations, that's the feed I needed :
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/64993
